# Fetch only categorized posts

Tags: wp-query, filters, query, wp-api

I'm using v2 of [WP-API](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/) to fetch posts and would like to exclude posts in the `Uncategorized` category. None of the following works:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[cat__not_in=1]
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[cat__not_in]=1
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[cat__not_in][]=1
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[category__not_in=1]
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[category__not_in]=1
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[category__not_in][]=1
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[category_name__not_in=uncategorized]
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[category_name__not_in]=uncategorized
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[category_name__not_in][]=uncategorized
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Could you try `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[category__not_in=1]` ?

Comment: Doesn't work either.

Comment: Similar question on SO asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34399986/2078474)

Answer (score 0):

`category__not_in` is a [private query var](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars). This means you can only use it when constructing a query in PHP, not in a url.

You would have to construct your own custom public query var and bind that to a filter that reads the category and then changes the query accordingly.